# Any simple mechanism in Mathematica to make a module with persistent state?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In C, I used to add the word static next to a variable when I define a local variable inside a function if I wanted the local variable value saved between calls.

This gave me the local scope protection of the variable name, but at the same time, the variable value was persistent. Was very useful to emulate a simple object which saves its own private state.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable#Static_local_variables

Is it possible to emulate this in Mathematica using `Module[]`? or `DynamicModule[]`?

(we know `Module[]` does not save local variables state by default, but What about using `DynamicModule[]`?)

No uses of packages. The context of using this is inside a `Manipulate[]`.

No `Module[]` can be outside Manipulate. Hence everything has to be something like this:

```
Manipulate[

    foo[]:=Module[{a,b,c},....];
    boo[]:=Module[{a,b,c},....];

      ... foo[] ..
      ... boo[]...
    ..,

    control_variables...,

    Initialization:>
    (
     .... global area....
    )
]
```

I tried using `DynamicModule` in place of `Module[]` above to do this, but `DynamicModules` can't be called as functions? and I could not figure how to do it.

**question is: is it possible to make a function remember the value of its local variables between calls, as one can do using C with local static variables for example?**

of course, one can't save the state in global variables, this the whole point of me asking this question. I'd like the Module state saved in a context that belongs to that Module only.

I am not asking for any advanced OO emulation. Just wanted to save few local variables used by a Module in a name scope that belong to that Module instead in a global context and have them be persistent between calls to the Module.

**Update**

To be clear, here is a very basic C example

```
#include <stdio.h>     

void my_add(void)  
{
 static int total = 0;

 total = total + 1;

 printf("current total %d\n",total);     
}

int main()
{
  int i;
  for(i = 1; i<=3; i++)
       my_add();

    return 0;
}

$ gcc ex.c
$ ./a.exe
current total 1
current total 2
current total 3
$
```

**Update 8:45 AM**

This is for WReach solution. Here is what I tried:

```
 Manipulate[
 n;
 Module[{total = 0},
  processA[] :=
   (
    total = total + 1
    )
  ];
 Module[{total = 0},
  processB[] :=
   (
    total = total + 1
    )
  ];

 Grid[{
   {"module A total=", processA[]},
   {"module B total=", processB[]}
   }],

 Button["press to update state", n++],
 {{n, 0}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {n}
 ]
```

[image]

The total remain 1 each time I hit the button. It is not saving the last value.

**Update 9:13 AM**

For WReach solution inside Manipulate:

Here is a test:

```
Manipulate[

 n;

 Grid[{
   {"module A result=", aResult}
   }],

 Button["press to update process A", {n++; aResult = processA[n]}],
 {{n, 0}, None},
 {{aResult, {}}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {n},
 Initialization :>
  (
   Module[{total = 0},
    processA[n_] :=
     (
      total = total + 1;
      {n, total}
      )
    ]
   )
 ]
```

On its own, it seems to work. But when I made a copy of the cell, and paste it to new cell. Then run the second Manipulate, to update the total there, then went back to the first Manipulate to update the total there, I see it is using the updated total from the second Manipulate. Hence it is global.

This is not allowed in a demo. Snap-shots are taken, and they can't share state (no global variables are allowed in a demo. The initialization section must not contain global shared data. But can contain functions that are called via parameters only from the Manipulate expression, no problem.

**update 9:40 AM**

Reply to Mr Wizard second example below, for the pattern he showed, which is the following:

```
Manipulate[
  {x, myAdd[]},
  {x, 1, 10},
  {{total, 0}, None},
  {{myAdd, (total += 1; total) &}, None}
]
```

The problem with this, is that the name `total` can not be used by 2 different functions. The name space for `total` is across the whole Manipulate.  What I'd want, using this pattern is something like this:

```
Manipulate[
 ctrl;
 Grid[{
   {"processA result=", processA[]},
   {"processB result=", processB[]}
   }],

 Button["step", ctrl++],

 {{ctrl, 0}, None},

 {{processA, Module[{total = 0}, total++] &}, None},
 {{processB, Module[{total = 0}, total++] &}, None},

 TrackedSymbols :> {ctrl}
 ]
```

You see, in the above, processA has its own local total, and processB as well. Same local name. The above does not work. If I replace the above with the following to make it 'work'

```
Manipulate[
 ctrl;
 Grid[{
   {"processA result=", processA[]},
   {"processB result=", processB[]}
   }],

 Button["step", ctrl++],

 {{ctrl, 0}, None},
 {{total, 0}, None},

 {{processA, Module[{}, total++] &}, None},
 {{processB, Module[{}, total++] &}, None},

 TrackedSymbols :> {ctrl}
 ]
```

Then processA and processB now share the same total variable. This defeats the whole point of having each be in separate name space, and yet be persistent over life time of call invocations.

**Update 10 AM**

Opps, I had bad way to writing that Module[] in the above example. That is why it was NOT working. Please ignore my 9:40 AM update. I am correcting it now, and will update in few minutes. It might actually be working.

**update 10:08 AM**

Ok, here is the scoop: In my 9:40 AM when I said "the above does not work", is because I had the setup wrong, wrong place of (). I corrected this. I am now showing the solution refered to below by WReach under the title **Avoiding Global Definitions**

The news is that it works for ONE manipulate. Once I copy the manipulate to another cell, the counters are shared between the 2 manipulates.

Here is an example: (corrected version of what I had above in 9:40 AM)

```
Manipulate[
 ctrl;
 Print["in top of Manipulate"];
 Grid[{
   {"processA current total=", aResult},
   {"processA current total=", bResult}
   }],

 Button["update A process", {ctrl++; aResult = processA[]}],
 Button["update B process", {ctrl++; bResult = processB[]}],

 {{ctrl, 0}, None},
 {{aResult, 0}, None},
 {{bResult, 0}, None},

 {{processA, Module[{total = 0}, ( total = total + 1; total) &]}, 
  None},
 {{processB, Module[{total = 0}, (total = total + 1; total) &]}, None},

 TrackedSymbols :> {ctrl}
 ]
```

[image]

The set up works, as long as there is one copy of the Manipulate. Once I copy the Manipulate itself to new cell, and modify that, the first gets updated. counters are global:

[image]

So, too bad, these solution do not work for me. Will try later the function context thing. But need to learn more about it first.

**update 12 PM**

To illustrate what I do now, in reply to MrWizard below, for each 'solver' I have, I pre-fix the name of each of its parameters by `pn`, where `n` is a solver ID number. So I have p1StepNumber, p2StepNumber, p3StepNumber, p1Solution, p2Solution, p3Solution, etc...

Then when I want to call solver 1, I pass it the p1* parameters and on return it returns back the solution and any updates, to be saved in the Manipulate Control->None area for later call, and so on.

Hence, state of each solver is kept/saved inside the Manipulate as Control->None variables. Since Manipulate is DynamicModule, these are saved between calls, and even when I close M and reopen it.

Here is a screen shot of partial listing of my Manipulate parameters in the Control-None area, to illustrate. all of these and much more are in one Manipulate. When user changes solver, the whole UI changes as well with a new layout specific for that solver.

Thanks to the use of Leonid Macro method, I am able to now do this easily :).

It would be better if I can save these 'inside' each solver, and have each solver be a separate Module, where each solver will save it own state, and Manipulate will just pass it the UI parameter each time it needs to refresh, and everything else is saved inside the solver(s) where they belong.

Not having even a struct to manage this, means each call I make has over 20-30 parameters to it.  Since I need to pass the solver all of its state each time, and get it back with it returns. It is not too bad, I just have to get used to making calls with 30 parameters each time, which is something I am not used. But I see no other clean way around it so far. That is why I asked this question.

[image]

**update 12/24/11 6 PM**
This is below response to suggestion by  Szabolcs and telefunkenvf14 to use function context name.

The conclusion I found is that this method does not work either. Same issue as the other methods.

Once I make a copy of the Manipulate itself, the variables become shared among the 2 copies of the Manipulates.

Below is an example showing the problem:

```
Remove["Global`*"]
Manipulate[
 ctrl;
 Print["in top of Manipulate"];
 Grid[{
   {"processA current total=", aResult},
   {"processA current total=", bResult}
   }],

 Button["update A process", {ctrl++; aResult = processA[]}],
 Button["update B process", {ctrl++; bResult = processB[]}],

 {{ctrl, 0}, None},
 {{aResult, 0}, None},
 {{bResult, 0}, None},

 {{processA, Module[{},
    (
      If[! ValueQ[processA`total], processA`total = 0];
       processA`total = processA`total + 1; 
      processA`total
      ) &]}, None},

 {{processB, Module[{},
    (
      If[! ValueQ[processB`total], processB`total = 0];
       processB`total = processB`total + 1; 
      processB`total
      ) &]}, None},

 TrackedSymbols :> {ctrl}
 ]
```

[image]

Now I copied the above into a new cell and clicked on the buttons, and I see the counters now advance from the values in the previous copy of Manipulate. So process`A is shared. It is local to each specific function.

[image]

Exactly the same issue with the other method tried, so this method does not work for me.

Comment: Pardon me, I am having trouble understanding.  Specifically which functions/symbols, and what do you mean by *between calls*?

Comment: @Nasser - Would it work to just set a variable with a specific subcontext name related to your function name? For example: myFunction`someValueToSave=stuffThatGetsEvaluatedOnFirstCallOfMyFunction

Comment: You could use a global variable and protect ("localize") it by placing it in a different context.  Something along ``fun[...] := Module[{...}, If[! ValueQ[fun`static], fun`static = 0] (* init variable for first time *); (* use fun`static here *) ... ]``.

Comment: @Mr Wizard, The function is a Module. The variable is a local variable for the Module.  Between calls, I mean local variables keep their values between calls. Please see small C example for illustration I am adding now above. Thanks

Comment: @Szablcs and telefunkenvf14, thanks for the thought of making function context. I have never used that before, sounds like it might work, will look more into it and try it later and update if it works.

Comment: @Szablcs and telefunkenvf14, please see my 6 pm update above. I've tried your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Module[{total = 0}
, myAdd[] := (total += 1; Print["current total ", total])
]
```

Use:

```
In[2]:= myAdd[]

        current total 1

In[3]:= myAdd[]

        current total 2

In[4]:= myAdd[]

        current total 3
```

For practical purposes, the module variable `total` is visible only to `myAdd`.  `Module` implements this by creating a new unique symbol whose name is generated from the supplied symbol (`total` in this case).  You can see this by evaluating an expression such as:

```
In[5]:= Module[{total}, total]

Out[5]= total$562
```

We can actually access the symbol used by `myAdd`:

```
In[6]:= Names["total*"]

Out[6]= {"total", "total$557", "total$562"}

In[7]:= total$557

Out[7]= 3
```

We can also see the effect of the renaming by examining the definition of `myAdd`:

```
In[8]:= ??myAdd

Global`myAdd
myAdd[]:=(total$557+=1; Print[current total, total$557])
```

**Use Inside Manipulate**

We can use this technique inside `Manipulate` thus:

```
Manipulate[
  {x, myAdd[]}
, {x, 1, 10}
, Initialization :>
    Module[{total = 0}
    , myAdd[] := (total += 1; total)
    ]
]
```

[image: Manipulate screenshot]

**Avoiding Global Definitions**

If we are desperate to avoid a global definition of `myAdd`, we can do this:

```
Manipulate[
  {x, myAdd[]}
, {x, 1, 10}
, { myAdd
  , Module[{total = 0}, (total += 1; total) &]
  , None
  }
]
```

This way, the definition of `myAdd` is localized within the `Manipulate`.  Note, however, that the symbol `myAdd` is still global, as are `x` and `total`.  This is due to the fact that the entire `Manipulate` expression is read into the global context.  If this is unsatisfactory, then we would have to place the entire expression into another context -- there is no avoiding the fact that symbols have to live in *some* context.

**Once More Into The Breach**

Okay, here is another attempt to address the added requirements:

```
Manipulate[
  Module[{f, g}
  , Module[{total = 0}, f[] := ++total]
  ; Module[{total = 0}, g[] := --total]
  ; Dynamic[{x, f[], g[]}]
  ]
, {x, 1, 10}
]
```

This solution has the following features:

- the definitions of `f` and `g` are localized to the cell
- the two occurrences of `total` are isolated from one another, and localized to the cell
- the `total` variables are not reset to zero whenever you manipulate `x`
- if you make a copy of the resulting output cell, the copy does not share any state with the first cell

Comment: thanks, but your solution is not working inside Manipulate. Manipulate expression is evaluated each time a control variable changes. Hence The Module is evaluated, resetting the total to zero each time. Hence no state is saved? Unless I made an error, please see my update of the example I have. I need this to run in a Manipulate context. Thanks

Comment: See the new section, _Use Inside Manipulate_.

Comment: I think the problem with `Initialization` is that it makes `myAdd[]` global.

Comment: `myAdd` (and `x` and `total`) will always be global -- the `Manipulate` expression is read into the global context.  It is possible to prevent the _definition_ of `myAdd` from landing in the global context -- see my edit.

Comment: @WReach, thanks for the Manipulate bit. But I tried it, it does NOT work. When I make a snapshot copy of the cell that contains Manipulate, to make a new Manipulate copy of it, into the same notebook, the variable total is now shared between the 2 cells (ie. between the 2 manipulates.) it is Global. Please see small code test I just made.

Comment: @Nasser, please try my method and comment on it.

Comment: If you want the values to be distinct after copying the cell, then the cell's `CellContext` must be set to `Cell`.  The easiest way to do this is to change the notebook's `CellContext` to `Cell` so that all output cells inherit that setting.  If you do this, then there is no need to take any further action to localize any of the symbols.

Comment: @WReach, please see my 10:08 AM update, where I tried your method above under "avoiding global definitions". thanks

Comment: I believe @Mr.Wizard's answer will do what you want.

Comment: @WReach, I am not sure I can change notebook stuff. This is a demonstration style sheet, and will go to WRI website. I do not know if I am allowed to do such changes in when I make snapshot. I have to check with WRI demonstration editor on this to see if it allowed to do. They are very strict about making changes to cell stype and such. I do not know anything about cellContext and such. Basically what is done at the end, is that one just copies the final Manipulate and paste it into a special cell in the notebook as snapshot. That is all. But I'll check on this. Thank you

Comment: Perhaps the new section _Once More Into The Breach_ is getting closer?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your needs, and I am not sure I do, then the form I suggested in this post may do what you want:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8552728/618728

That is, using controls like: `{{x, 0}, None}`

Adapting your appended example, does this work?

```
Manipulate[
 n;
 processA[] := (total = total + 1);
 processB[] := (total = total + 1);
 Grid[{{"module A total=", processA[]}, {"module B total=", processB[]}}], 
 Button["press to update state", n++],
 {{n, 0}, None},
 {{total, 0}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {n}
]
```

Adapting WReach's recent example:

```
Manipulate[
  {x, myAdd[]},
  {x, 1, 10},
  {{total, 0}, None},
  {{myAdd, (total += 1; total) &}, None}
]
```

Here is an example using your latest question update.  As far as I can tell this works.  I suggest you find a way to work around the need for separate symbols.

```
Manipulate[ctrl;
 Grid[{
   {"processA current total=", aResult},
   {"processA current total=", bResult}
 }], 
 Button["update A process", {ctrl++; aResult = processA[]}],
 Button["update B process", {ctrl++; bResult = processB[]}],
 {{ctrl, 0}, None},
 {{aResult, 0}, None},
 {{bResult, 0}, None},
 {{total1, 0}, None},
 {{total2, 0}, None},
 {{processA, (++total1) &}, None},
 {{processB, (++total2) &}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {ctrl}
]
```

Comment: MrWizard, your first example does not work for me. processA and processB are sharing the same state (total). For your second example, it does not work for me either. the total you are using can be used by 2 different modules. Please see my update now, to show what I want, using this second pattern. (but it does not work), thanks

Comment: It took a while for us to elicit the _real_ question, but it sounds to me like your edit does what the OP wants (which has nothing to do with simulating C `static`).  +1

Comment: @WReach, unfortunately, MrWizard solution (shown above in the second example) does not work for me. The counter shown called total will be now be shared between more than one function that want to use this name. I thought my question was clear. but it looks like I did not explain it well.

Comment: @Nasser why can't you create multiple symbols? `total1`, `total2`, `total3`, etc.?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, yes ofcourse, but this is EXACTLY what I do now. But I have very large demo. Over 7,000 lines so far, and will go to be over 20,000 lines at least. It is a PDE numerical solver toolbox. For each solver I have, it requires many parameters. I save all of these as Manipulate Control->None. Big mess. different solvers have similar parameters and states associated with them. demo runs in state-machine setting. So state is saved during run to allow user to stop/run/step/pause/ etc.. And since there is no struct data type in M, managing such large number of variables is a problem.

Comment: @Nasser in that case I am sorry that I cannot be more helpful.  I have never written a 7000 line *Mathematica* app, much less a Demo of that size.  Have you tried contacting WRI support directly and requesting assistance?